# How can I know if 3D aperiodic systems are not interacting with each other using Quantum ESPRESSO?

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, quantum-dots

I wanted to observe the Projected Density of States of InP system passivated with Hydride ions. For that, the following input file was created.

```
&CONTROL
 calculation='scf',
 outdir='./outdir',
 prefix='InPH',
 pseudo_dir='.',
 verbosity='low',
 tprnfor=.true.,
 tstress=.true.,
/
&SYSTEM
  ibrav = 0
  A =   28.95873
  nat = 38
  ntyp = 3
 ecutwfc=50,
 ecutrho=400,
 input_dft='pbe',
 occupations='smearing',
 starting_charge(1) = +3.0
 starting_charge(2) = -3.0
 starting_charge(3) = -1.0
 smearing='mv',
 degauss=0.005d0,
                       
/

&ELECTRONS
 conv_thr=1d-07,
 mixing_beta=0.7d0,
/

CELL_PARAMETERS {alat}
  1.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000 
  0.000000000000000   1.000000000000000   0.000000000000000 
  0.000000000000000   0.000000000000000   1.000000000000000 
ATOMIC_SPECIES
  In  114.81800   In.pbe-dn-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
   P   30.97300   P.pbe-n-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
   H    1.00750   H.pbe-kjpaw_psl.1.0.0.UPF
ATOMIC_POSITIONS {crystal}
In   0.301777000000000   0.515510000000000   0.403224000000000 
In   0.489752000000000   0.303558000000000   0.415264000000000 
In   0.503499000000000   0.505059000000000   0.408072000000000 
In   0.501909000000000   0.513929000000000   0.598334000000000 
In   0.296909000000000   0.419582000000000   0.514790000000000 
In   0.492873000000000   0.398390000000000   0.315705000000000 
In   0.497050000000000   0.408959000000000   0.504514000000000 
In   0.510066000000000   0.608991000000000   0.499706000000000 
In   0.390717000000000   0.315763000000000   0.518452000000000 
In   0.401476000000000   0.501161000000000   0.310056000000000 
In   0.402099000000000   0.515299000000000   0.498794000000000 
In   0.602463000000000   0.505451000000000   0.505306000000000 
In   0.393310000000000   0.407603000000000   0.415739000000000 
In   0.399042000000000   0.422615000000000   0.605304000000000 
In   0.406187000000000   0.607978000000000   0.395822000000000 
In   0.594811000000000   0.396109000000000   0.407363000000000 
 P   0.448966000000000   0.459054000000000   0.454312000000000 
 P   0.440175000000000   0.354263000000000   0.367464000000000 
 P   0.445543000000000   0.367260000000000   0.559101000000000 
 P   0.455293000000000   0.551606000000000   0.354347000000000 
 P   0.454803000000000   0.563518000000000   0.546515000000000 
 P   0.348592000000000   0.457212000000000   0.361770000000000 
 P   0.351886000000000   0.472249000000000   0.553642000000000 
 P   0.546899000000000   0.448683000000000   0.359923000000000 
 P   0.548477000000000   0.458559000000000   0.552198000000000 
 P   0.341560000000000   0.363924000000000   0.467769000000000 
 P   0.354314000000000   0.565300000000000   0.448689000000000 
 P   0.543486000000000   0.352663000000000   0.460158000000000 
 P   0.556644000000000   0.554867000000000   0.452761000000000 
 H   0.642987000000000   0.469927000000000   0.474034000000000 
 H   0.481225000000000   0.651348000000000   0.464263000000000 
 H   0.255512000000000   0.450777000000000   0.480210000000000 
 H   0.526102000000000   0.358078000000000   0.281589000000000 
 H   0.522877000000000   0.266367000000000   0.377674000000000 
 H   0.360938000000000   0.390592000000000   0.642932000000000 
 H   0.271709000000000   0.550732000000000   0.361406000000000 
 H   0.371546000000000   0.639032000000000   0.354239000000000 
 H   0.367327000000000   0.536759000000000   0.271849000000000 

K_POINTS {automatic}
 1 1 1  0 0 0
```

Here the quantum dot has 13 P$^{-3}$ ions, 16 In$^{+3}$ ions and 9 H$^{-}$. Hence the starting charge.

[image]

> **How can I know if the systems are not interacting with each other? The diameter of the system is 8 angstrom and the unit cell
> is cubic with a cell parameter of 28 angstroms**

NOTE: The convergence of observables w.r.t variation in Cell parameters (as Tristan suggested) is one method. But if there are other more quantifiable methods like calculating the electron density in between two particles in adjacent cells, it would be nice to know :)

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 9):

Since QE is a planewave based code and we are talking about cells, its important to realize its periodic so its always interacting with itself to some degree.  The only way to check if its sufficiently not interacting is to increase the cell size and see if your property changes.  If it does, repeat again until its converged just like kpoints or energy cutoffs.

Comment: +1, Thank You for your answer! This is correct but rather than identifying the parameters for minimal interaction by the variation in the observables wrt cell size, I was hoping if there was a method to observe the real space electron density around the particle.

Comment: Hmm someone may know around here, this seems like something that could have an answer along those lines.

Comment: I don't know if QE is able to do the following. SIESTA, that it is also for periodic system (is mandatory to input the crystal parameters), is able to detect the type of system from the atom configuration and cell parameters. It can detect if the system is a molecule, a slab, or a crystal and then, treat accordingly.